# Инициализация дочернего объекта родительским C#

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование, конструктор

Имею класс Visualiser который наследуется от VisSet.
Теперь мне нужно создать конструктор Visualiser(VisSet obj) который инициализируется объектом родительского класса, как это сделать, что бы не перебирать все свойства родительского класса?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.1.php

Comment: @TEA Если вы имеете в виду использование `Visualiser(VisSet obj):base(obj)` то это не решает проблемы, мне все равно придется строить конструктор который затем будет инициализировать родительский обект из входящего объекта, а что если родительский не имеет такого конструктора?

Comment: Хотелось бы что то вроде `Visualiser(VisSet obj):base=obj` ну или хотя бы понять как без перебирания полей сделать конструктор `VisSet(VisSet obj)`

Comment: Смотрите паттерн Декоратор

Answer (score 0):

На текущий момент, единственное решение: Убрать наследование и сделать вложенным классом